# Heating a rod of any material at one end without losing heat to the surrounding

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I am interested in learning about heat flow but I am a noob.

Suppose there is a rod of finite length that can conduct heat. Suppose we always keep one end of the rod at a temperature say $u$. Will the other rod also reach the same temperature after some time if we assume that heat cannot be lost to the surrounding?

Is this possible for any type of material that conducts heat?

My intuition says yes as long as conductivity is non zero. Am I right?

Comment: Your intuition is correct.

Comment: BTW, I'm hard-pressed to imagine a material that does **not** conduct heat!  (other than unobtanium, which is used in all Freshman Physics Labs)